# Subtract 2 byte values in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the 85% of the total disk value in the below code and then subtract it with the free value. Need to create a text file with the resulted value to test for alerts in SNOW.

```
$GetFreeSpace = Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Used,Free
[int64]$Freespace = $GetFreeSpace.Free


# Get disk size 85%
$disk = Get-Volume -DriveLetter C 
$totalSize = $disk.Size
[int64]$eightyFivePercent = $totalSize * 0.85

# File to be created for Warning Alert (85%)
[int64]$File_size_for_warning = $eightyFivePercent - $GetFreeSpace

$file_size = $File_size_for_warning 
$file_Path "C:\Script\test_file_warning_alert.txt"
$stream = [System.IO.File]::CreateText($filePath)
$stream.BaseStream.SetLength($fileSize)
$stream.Close()
```

but while doing I am getting the below error in subtraction

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
At line:11 char:1
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the output of $GetFreeSpace you'll notice it is an object not a value.  It looks like you know that since you've got this line.

```
[int64]$Freespace = $GetFreeSpace.Free
```

but here you are using the object not the value you've created.

```
[int64]$File_size_for_warning = $eightyFivePercent - $GetFreeSpace
```

Just change that line to

```
[int64]$File_size_for_warning = $eightyFivePercent - $FreeSpace
```